# Codeigniter syntax $this->db->list_fields to get many columns from many tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hi i have Codeigniter function

```
function get_info2($item_id, $profil)
{
    $arrayku = explode(',', $item_id);
    $hasilsplit0 = $arrayku[0];
    $hasilsplit1 = str_replace("%20"," ",$arrayku[1]);

    $this->db->select("i.item_id,i.name as name, i.category as category, 
    i.supplier_id as supplier_id, i.item_number as item_number, i.product_id 
   as product_id, i.description as description, i.size as size, 
   i.tax_included as tax_included,  i.cost_price as cost_price, IF(pt.name IS 
   NULL, i.unit_price, itp.unit_price) AS unit_pricebaru, i.promo_price as 
   promo_price, i.start_date as start_date, i.end_date as end_date, 
   i.reorder_level as reorder_level, i.allow_alt_description as 
   allow_alt_description, i.is_serialized as is_serialized, i.image_id as 
   image_id, i.override_default_tax as override_default_tax, i.is_service as 
   is_service, i.deleted as deleted
    ", FALSE);
            $this->db->from('items i');
    $this->db->join('items_tier_prices itp','itp.item_id=i.item_id','left');
    $this->db->join("price_tiers pt","pt.id=itp.tier_id and pt.name='".$hasilsplit1."'","left");
    $this->db->where('i.item_id', $hasilsplit0);
    $this->db->where('i.deleted', 0);
            $this->db->order_by('pt.name', 'desc');
            $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        $item_obj=new stdClass();

        $fields = $this->db->list_fields('?????');

        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $item_obj->$field='';
        }

        return $item_obj;
    }

}
```

the query works successfully without error.

my question is:
    how to write/get query column result properly with many columns from 3 join tables items, items_tier_prices, price_tiers (pls see query above)?

```
 $fields = $this->db->list_fields('?????');
```

anyone pls help. or if i have mistake pls fix my code so i can return $item_obj properly;

sorry for bad english.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `$query->list_fields()` with no argument should give you all the fields.